# tableau view with dimensions totals, static values and calculation

Tags: visualization, tableau, data-table

I try to create a table like the one following.
I got 1 line product, 1 dimension "zones" and I want to add few columns : total for pieces on a line, a fixe value for a product(stock mini), a calculated field stock mini - total an an icone to tell me if the sctock mini - total is > or < to 0
After struggling I manage to create my columns, but I found no solution to add a shape or icon only with tableau Online.

| Nom Produit | Stock mini | Commande proposé > 0 | Commande Proposée Total | Zone 1 | Zone 2 | Zone 3 | zone x... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A - COUETTE SYNTHETIQUE | (fixed value per line) | RED ICONE | (stockmini – total line) | sum(count table ) | count(zone x) |  |  |
| A - COUVERTURE LAINE | 100 | green icon | 0 | 14 | 5 | 5 | 4 |
| A - DESSUS DE LIT SIMPLE MATELASSE | 20 | RED ICONE | 5 | 10 | 5 | 10 |  |

Comment: What have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: Hello I endend with a table that looks nearly how I want. the probleme was how to have the 4 column on the left. Now I got  3 of then, but I still need to find a way to add the icone only with tableau online. (i'm on linux I'm not able to use tableau desktop)

Comment: sorry @rubengavidia0x I just realized that my description disappeared of the post